Major product of reaction between 1,1-dibromo-2-(pent-4-en-1-yl)cyclopropane and methyllithium
What is the major product of the reaction between 1,1-dibromo-2-(pent-4-en-1-yl)cyclopropane and methyllithium in diethyl ether?

I suppose the nucleophilic double bond will react with the electrophilic carbon, but I cannot figure out how the second bromine atom will be substituted. I cannot find anywhere what MeLi is being used for in this reaction.

The MeLi does a metal-halogen exchange and I think you are going to generate a carbene

@Waylander Thanks, Wikipedia(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbene) also seems to suggest that. It also gives the correct final product for my reaction.
